# What is the best way to handle the react GQL configurations with all query and mutation policies and for file upload?

Tags: gql, react-gql

Need to know the best practice to maintain the react GQL configurations settings where we set all query, mutation, or other policies, and the better way to handle file upload setting?

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches with different use cases. The following code might be helpful in your case.

```
import {
  ApolloClient,
  ApolloLink,
  DefaultOptions,
  InMemoryCache,
} from "@apollo/client";
import { onError } from "@apollo/client/link/error";
import { createUploadLink } from "apollo-upload-client";

const authMiddleware = new ApolloLink((operation: any, forward: any) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token") || null;
  operation.setContext({
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  });
  return forward(operation);
});

const defaultOptions: DefaultOptions = {
  watchQuery: {
    fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network",
    errorPolicy: "ignore",
  },
  query: {
    fetchPolicy: "network-only",
    errorPolicy: "all",
  },
  mutate: {
    errorPolicy: "all",
  },
};

const errorLink = onError(
  ({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation, forward }: any) => {
    // You can modify do something with the errors
  }
);

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  connectToDevTools: true,
  link: ApolloLink.from([
    errorLink,
    authMiddleware,
    createUploadLink({
      uri: process.env.REACT_APP_GRAPHQL_URI || "http://localhost:3001/graphql",
    }),
  ]),
  defaultOptions: defaultOptions,
});

export default client;
```